# Do you native speakers pronounce "don't ask" as /doʊnæsk/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, silent-letter

[This page](http://pronuncian.com/when-t-doesnt-sound-like-t/) said

> The /t/ is optionally silent when it follows /n/ and precedes a vowel
>   sound, /r/ (including all r-controlled vowels) or a syllabic /l/.

do you native speakers say "**don't ask**" as `/doʊnæsk/`?

Comment: Your question reminds me of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKbkArYyics). (Yes, _don't ask_ often gets a "silent t".)

Comment: "Don't ask don't tell policy", I hear only one t sound.

Comment: There's going to be a lot of variation on this - even in the US, between different regions, and even different settings.  I could pronounce it one way to my boss and the other way to my friends at a bar.

Answer (score 1):

I am a native speaker of a very general General American and I would say /doʊnʔæsk/ in all cases regardless of formality of speech (I always glottalize /t/ syllable-finally). I might not even understand /doʊnæsk/ if the context didn't make it clear, and certainly it sounds excessively colloquial to me. I never omit /t/ after a nasal; "banter" will have the strong aspirated /t/ even in casual speech. You can't go wrong by pronouncing the t.

Answer (score 0):

Being Australian I tend to use a lot of slang in my general conversations. In this case, I would utilise the latter, simply because it rolls of the tongue better. In formal situations though in which I am paying attention to my speech, I would say the former.

Comment: :) before someone downvoted you - there is no former or latter in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an accent thing.

I'm also Australian, and notice many people drop the "t" in this situation.

However, interestingly it seems to only be after _on't words, and not _an't words.

For example, "don't ask" becomes "doun ask", "won't ask" becomes "woun ask", but "can't ask" becomes "carnt ask" - I suppose because can is the opposite of can't - so silence on the t would lead to confusion.

Though I have heard "carn ask"...again due to accent.

doesn't...this is another one that depends on accent. I've often heard it pronounced as "dozen".

Australian English is a lot more slurred and relaxed than England English though, and will differ from state to state.

In Tasmania, people often sound half asleep ;)

"Howz yuz goinn darl" (meaning how are you going darling) and "howz arz ya" (how are you) is a common greeting that I used to cringe at when I moved to Tasmania!

It is common here for complete strangers to call each other "Darl" (meaning darling) but never heard this in other states of Australia.